# Sending data into Google DoubleClick Search

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, postman, google-apis-explorer

So here's a bit of context. I am unable to use the google api client library has I am integrating from within SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) C# script task. At the moment I am spiking out a solution.

I have managed to create an auth_token using a .p12 using certificate file for serviced accounts using a .net WebClient class. So the authorisation is not a problem I get as I get a successfull auth_token using the bare bones .net code.

The next thing I need to do is send some json data to the endpoint:
https://www.googleapis.com/doubleclicksearch/v2/conversion/insert

So I am using the auth_code I have generated and calling the end point above using the below c# snippet below, I have written with some test json I have taken from the help pages here [DoubleClick Search Help Pages](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-search/v2/how-tos/conversions/insert)

The pages suggest the data needs to be sent like this:-

```
POST  https://www.googleapis.com/doubleclicksearch/v2/conversion
Authorization: Bearer your OAuth 2.0 access token
Content-type: application/json
{
 "kind": "doubleclicksearch#conversionList",
  "conversion" : [{
    "clickId" : "COiYmPDTv7kCFcP0KgodOzQAAA", // Replace with a click ID from your site
    "conversionId" : "test_20130906_04",
    "conversionTimestamp" : "1378710000000",
    "segmentationType" : "FLOODLIGHT",
    "segmentationName" : "Test",
    "type": "TRANSACTION",
    "revenueMicros": "1000000",
   "currencyCode": "USD"
  }]
 }
```

C# snippet:-

```
public static HttpStatusCode SendData(string accessToken, string data, string url, out string responseData)
{
    try
    {
        using ( var client = new WebClient { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 })
        {
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.93 Safari/537.36";
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = string.Format("Bearer {0}", accessToken);
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/json";
            var result = client.UploadString(url, "PUT", data);
            responseData = result;
            return HttpStatusCode.Created;
        }
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        using (var response = e.Response)
        {
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
            using (var errdata = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (errdata != null)
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(errdata))
                    {
                        responseData = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        return 0;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    responseData = null;
    return 0;
}
```

And I am getting the below error returned, what am I doing wrong?

```
{
  "error": {
     "errors": [
       {
       "domain": "global",
       "reason": "requestValidation",
       "message": "The request was not valid. Details: [Permission denied]"
      }
    ],
    "code": 400,
    "message": "The request was not valid. Details: [Permission denied]"
   }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Andrew